# Embed custom watermark from text in a Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

I want to generate a document with some text embedded in the background (like a letterhead in business letters).
I came up with a rather daunting method, where one can:

1. fill up the background text, save the document as .pdf
2. Convert .pdf to .png
3. In new, blank document (Office 365): Design -> Watermark -> Custom Watermark -> Image

It works well, but the same template is applied for all pages within the document. It is important, that other background template will be shown on the second page.
Therefore,

1. Is there a better (quicker, more professional) way to embed custom template from text to the background?
2. **How can I create a document with two pages containing different background texts in the form of a watermark?**

Comment: Hello, try to make Sections in your Word document. The greek translate is Ενότητα

Comment: Good thinking! However, according to this [1] post, it can't be done with a "watermark" facility :(
[1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_2010/different-watermark-in-different-pages/8ceb1799-0a15-4733-8dae-8b722f0aa537)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watermarks are essentially images placed into the Header level of the Word document. Word's built-in Insert Watermark function places the same image in all Headers of all Sections in the document.

I said **all** Headers and I said that on purpose. Each Section of a document has 3 potential Headers. They are:

1. Primary Page, which is the odd numbered page.
2. Even Page
3. Different First Page, which means a unique Header for the first page of a specific section.

If you have a 2-page document and it is only 1-Section and you want a unique "watermark" image on the first page and a different "watermark" image on the second page, do the following.

- Open the Header area of the document (do this from the Header menu on the Insert tab) and choose the Edit Header option.
- From the contextual Design tab for Header & Footer Tools that opens, mark the Different First Page checkbox.
- With the Header area open Insert the image you want to be the watermark for the First Page into the First Page header area.
- After inserting it, right click on the image and select the Wrapping text option of Behind Text. If you want to reduce the intensity of the image, also change its opacity. And finally drag the image to the position you want it to appear on the page.
- Now scroll down and perform the same two steps above, to insert a new unique image on the next Header in this Section of the document.

Close the Header area and you are done. If you are also using Odd and Even Page Headers, you will have to temporarily insert a page break into your document, so you can properly set the Even Page Header.